# Can I edit contents of Channel Files field in Safecracker Form?

Tags: safecracker, devdemon, channel-files

Can I build a page with SafeCracker that will allow me...

1) Upload files via Channel Files field? I'm running EE 2.5.5 (SafeCracker 2.1).

2) Manage (Edit, Delete, Add) files already previously submitted?

I wasn't able to find much info on the second question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Channel Form (Safecracker) is supported. You can upload files and edit/delete/add them just like your CP publish form.

Brad