# How do I upload a file from my template to my Channel Files field?

Tags: safecracker, file-uploads, channel-files

Apologies if this has already been asked and answered, but I couldn't find any tangible example on how to actually do this.

All I'm trying to do is create a template in ExpressionEngine, and upload a small JPG file to a channel field that's set to a [Channel Files](http://www.devdemon.com/expressionengine-addons/channel-files) field type.

As [this post](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/26681/can-i-edit-contents-of-channel-files-field-in-safecracker-form) suggests, it should work the same as uploading to a regular File field type using the [Channel Form](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/add-ons/channel/channel_form/index.html) tag, but it doesn't seem to be uploading the file. The code below works perfectly for the normal File field type for adding new entries:

```
{exp:channel:form channel='other_details'}

    <input type='hidden' name='title' value='Some new title here.' />

    <input type="hidden" name="custom_upload_hidden_file" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom_upload_hidden_dir" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom_upload_directory" value="2">
    <input type="file" name="custom_upload">

    <input type='submit' value='Upload' />

{/exp:channel:form}
```

The file upload location is a location with ID 2, which is perfect, but I need to upload the file to a Channel Files field type, not a normal File field type. How do you achieve this?

Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do this and see the markup used for channel form is to use the following.

```
{exp:channel:form channel='other_details'}

    <input type='hidden' name='title' value='Some new title here.' />


    {!-- This will output the correct syntax for your file upload field specified in the cPanel. --}

    {field:custom_upload}

    <input type='submit' value='Upload' />

{/exp:channel:form}
```

Comment: Matts Id John: Bro you the man. Thnks a mill.